# Clutter: Perspective, Skew, and Matrices

Tags: clutter, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

Is there a way to change the clutter perspective for a given container or widget?

The clutter perspective controls how all the clutter actors on the screen are displayed when rotated, translated, scaled, etc.

1. What I would really like to do is to **change the perspective's origin from the center of the screen to another coordinate**.

I have messed with a few of the stage methods. However, I  haven't had much luck understanding some of the results, and often I hit some stability issues.

I know there are transformation matrices that do all the logic under the hood, and there are documented ways to change the transform matrices. Honestly, I haven't researched much further and just though I would ask for guidance before spending a lot of time on it.

2. Which leads me to another question regarding the matrices and transformations. Can one of these matrices **be used to skew an actor?** Or deform it into a trapezoid, etc? And any idea how to get started on that, ie. what a skew matrix would look like?
3. Finally, does anyone know why the clip path was deprecated? It seems that would have worked for what I ultimately want to do: **draw irregular shaped 2d objects on the screen** If I can implement an answer to question 2, then I guess a clip box with a transformation can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

**1**, I do not know if (or how) one might change the Clutter stage's focal point.

**2** A skew or [shear transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) is easy enough to construct, and can be implemented in the GJS Clutter functions `Clutter.Actor.set_transform(T)` and `Clutter.Actor.set_child_transform(T)` where `T` is a Clutter.Matrix .

This does present another problem, however, for the current codebase; and this leads to another question. (I guess I should post it somewhere else). But, when a transform is set on a clutter actor (or its children), the rest of the actor's properties are ignored. This has the added effect that the Tweener library cannot be used for animation of these properties.

**3** Finally, one can use Cairo  to draw irregular shaped objects and paths on a Clutter actor, however, the reactive area for the actor (ie. mouse-enter and -leave events) will still be for the entire actor, not defined by the Cairo path.